# TableController forces Id field to be a string

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I'm buliding an app with an Azure back end. According to all the tutorials (like this one: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/), Microsoft recommend that you use the `TableController<TData>` class to get and set data using the mobile interface. This offers all of the features of ODataControllers, together with offline sync support. However, the constraint is that `TData` must derive from `ITableData`, which in turn means that the ID fields in my tables must be `string` fields.

Is there a workaround for this, that does not break Entity Framework? If my entities are stored in my database with a sequential identity ID field, does this mean I can't use `TableController<TData>` in conjunction with OData?

Answer (score 1):

There is a big reason for having the string Id.

Let's say you have two clients, both offline.  The server says the last ID is 1.
Client A inserts data, which gets ID 2, but it's offline.  Client B then inserts data, ALSO with ID 2, but it's offline.  Client A then syncs its data and the record gets accepted.  Client B then syncs its data and there is a conflict.

To get around this, each ID must be globally unique.  So use a string which contains (generally) a GUID.

There are ways to get around the issue you are reporting.  For example, I showed a methodology in my blog post: https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-19-asp-net-table-controllers/ - this uses a separate table to hold the mobile data and then a view to merge the original table with the mobile data.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll have a play soon. Quick question: why can't we just assign negative IDs to unsynced data?

Comment: Probably because that would be a can of worms, now that I think about it. Mutable IDs -- not cool.

Comment: Yeah - complete can of worms.  The likelihood of the offline sync store ending up in a bad state is high with mutable Ids